# What does “this time around” mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of “this time around” why not just this time . The full sentence is

> This time around, she wants to get it right!

This time around means that it happened before and it will happen again? The context is a publication for the real relationship life.

The real question is why they did not use only "this time" but they used "this time around".  What will be the difference between both ?

Comment: What do you think it means?  What research have you done to try and find the answer?  Please add more detail or the question is likely to be closed.

Comment: this time around means that it happened before and it will happen again ? the context is a publication for the real relationship life

Comment: the real question is why they did not use only this time but they used this time around. what will be the difference between both ?

Comment: Thanks, I've added those to your question.  That should be good.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"This time around", as you guess, means that it has happened before, and may happen again.  "Around" evokes an image of a *repeating cycle*, which is most often thought of as *circular*.

The main difference between "this time" and "this time around" is the implied caution that the cycle will continue until something happens to break it.

> **This time**, she wants to get it right.

= it has happened at least once before, but this time she will do it differently

> **This time around**, she wants to get it right

= it has happened at least once before (but possibly more), and if she doesn't do it differently this time, she expects that it will keep happening the same way.

Comment: I am not the OP but I think your explanation is logical and makes good sense. But, I don't get it pretty well.
I am sorry but, is that really the meaning of `this time around`?
So do you mean `this time around` in your example sounds less optimistic than `this time`?

Answer (score 0):

As far as my knowledge goes , this idiom is used to convey the mood that betokens a slight but sure change in routine .